# react-native-maps: gray map after apk build

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, react-native, react-native-maps

I have a RN app that uses `react-native-maps`. I was able to successfully render the Map in the Android and iOS Emulators, but when I build it out (using Expo), the app works but the Map renders as a Gray screen with the Google logo on the bottom left-hand corner.

- I have an API key and have enabled all of the essential APIs in the
  Google Developer Console.
- I have only tested this on a physical Android device.

So,

1. What am I missing?
2. Should I consider using Mapbox instead?

EDIT:

I did not add anything to a build.gradle or anything of the sort from the Android Studio end; just front-end stuff. Is this required?

Comment: are you setting it to a specific lat long? is that correct on the device? do you have access to location?

Comment: @oma yes a specific lat lng, should be correct on the device, and I should have access to location. I wasn't prompted. However, when I tried to install it, I was prompted with a warning whether or not to install because it wasn't sure who the developer was (me), so I installed anyways.

Comment: https://forums.expo.io/t/google-maps-blank-not-loading-on-android/15529/7

Believe this is a known issue to the Expo devs. However, the issue in the link is in regards to Android only.

Answer (score 3):

I face same problem of greyed map, when use LocationView of  react-native-location-view. Greyed Map resolved by  Enable Maps SDK for Android. Follow as shown  in [image]

Comment: This should be the approved answer, saved my day!

Answer (score 2):

Enable Maps SDK for Android in your developer console
https://console.developers.google.com